# How to enable ctrl+del to delete to end of word to the right of cursor in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

In virtually every Windows program except Excel, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> deletes the characters to the right of the cursor up to the end of the word.

When editing the contents of a cell in Excel 2010, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> deletes the characters to the right of the cursor *up to the end of the line*. Worse still, the location of the end of the line varies depending on whether you are editing the cell in place or via the formula bar.

Is there some way to configure Excel so that it behaves like pretty much everything else in the Windows-verse (including other Office programs like Word, PowerPoint, and Outlook)?

Comment: Workaround: Ctrl-Shift-Right Arrow, then Del

Comment: Interesting idea, but doing this on Excel selects (and thus deletes) any punctuation following the word you're in, whereas ctrl+del everywhere else leaves any following punctuation. This seems to be because double-clicking a word in an Excel cell selects following punctuation, whereas in other programs it does not.

Comment: With the Ctrl + Shift +Right Arrow method, while the word is still highlighted, Shift + Left Arrow will move the selection back one character. You can do this multiple times.

Comment: Of course I can manually adjust the selection to match what I want to delete, but that calls for a lot more time and attention than simply hitting ctrl+del and knowing that it will do the right thing.I understand that we're in workaround territory, but it's important to acknowledge that the workaround has shortcomings that themselves have to be worked around.

Comment: I agree that it would be better if Microsoft provided more consistent behaviour. On the other hand, if you spend a lot of time editing text with punctuation in Excel cells, perhaps your data (or at least the editing of it) is better suited to some other application.